# Reflection colors are lost on high resolution MeshRegion

Tags: color, mesh, display

Mathematica is able to manage two kinds of reflections :

- With a simple color directive (`Blue`, `RBGColor[...]`...), one can specify the diffuse reflection.
- With the directive `Specularity[Yellow,...]`, one can specify the specular reflection.

  That gives nice effects :

[image]

(Note that the light source is White.)

Here is the code :

```
region00=DiscretizeRegion[
Polygon[{{-1,-1,0},{1,-1,0},{1,1,0},{-1,1,0}}],
MaxCellMeasure->0.0003,
MeshCellStyle->{1-> Black, 2-> Directive[Specularity[Yellow,100],Blue]}];

lightSourcePosition={0,0.8,0.2};
lightSource=DiscretizeRegion[Ball[lightSourcePosition,0.02],  
  MaxCellMeasure->0.2,MeshCellStyle->{1-> Gray, 2-> Gray,3-> Gray}];

Show[region00,
lightSource,
(*Graphics3D[{Red,Sphere[lightSourcePosition,0.02]}],*)  
Axes-> True,AxesLabel->{"X","Y","Z"},Lighting-> 
{{"Point",White,lightSourcePosition}},ImageSize-> 800,  
ViewCenter->{0.5`,0.5`,0.5`},ViewPoint->{0.027,-3.14,1.2},  
ViewVertical->{-0.017,-0.49,14.5}]
```

[image]

But when I set `MaxCellMeasure->0.0002`, colors are lost :

[image]

Sometime only the specular reflection color is lost.

Any workaround ?

Comment: maybe a candidate for the tag "Bug"

Comment: I don't thinks so. It is meaningfull to keep perfomance for complicated `MeshRegion`s. For graphical purposes, the classical `GraphicsComplex` should be prefered.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I use Region because I want to use the new fonctionnality `RegionUnion` **on** 3D meshRegion. It's new to Mathematica 11.2

Comment: That's fine. Still, you can convert your `MeshRegion` to a `GraphicsComplex` with `Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[region00],MeshCells[region00, 2]]]` and use classical graphics directives on that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that the option `PlotTheme` for large `MeshRegion`s is automatically set to `"LargeMesh"` for performance reasons. Try the following:

```
region00 = 
 DiscretizeRegion[
  Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.000003, 
  MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black, 2 -> Directive[Specularity[Yellow, 100], Blue]},
  PlotTheme -> "SmoothShading"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

One can also set the system option for `"LargeMeshThreshold"` to be greater than the number of mesh cells (default threshold is `1000`):

```
SetSystemOptions["RegionOptions" -> {"LargeMeshThreshold" -> 2000}];
Show[region00, lightSource, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Point", White, lightSourcePosition}}, 
 ImageSize -> 600, ViewCenter -> {0.5`, 0.5`, 0.5`}, 
 ViewPoint -> {0.027, -3.14, 1.2}, 
 ViewVertical -> {-0.017, -0.49, 14.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]