# How to show plastic wrap with Mathematica 3D graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I can make a nice wave picture with the following function:

```
Plot3D[1/(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + 3)*(Cos[2*(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + ArcTan[x, y])]),
{x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}, {-3, 3}},
Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500,  ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, I want to change the graphics options so that it looks like it's made of transparent but shiny plastic wrap. I tried various `Lighting`, `Specularity`, and `Opacity` options, but nothing seemed to work. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a link to an image that demonstrates the effect you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to re-use [this approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157307/5467).

Here is my best and definitive proposition :

```
zview=1;

region00=Plot3D[1/(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + 3)*(Cos[2*(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + ArcTan[x, y])]),
{x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}, {-3, 3}},
Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500,  ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"] //
DiscretizeGraphics[#,PlotTheme -> "SmoothShading",MeshCellStyle->{(*1-> Black,*) 2-> Directive[Specularity[Yellow,100],Opacity[0.8],Blue]}]&;

region01=PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron";"OctahedronFourCompound";"MathematicaPolyhedron"]  //
DiscretizeGraphics[#,PlotTheme -> "SmoothShading",MeshCellStyle->{(*1-> Black,*) 2-> Directive[Glow[Red],Specularity[White,200](*,White*)]}]& //Scale[#,2]& //Translate[#,{10,0,-.5}]&;

coeff=20;

lightSourcePosition=coeff{0,0.8,0.2};
lightSource=DiscretizeRegion[Ball[lightSourcePosition,coeff 0.02],  
  MaxCellMeasure->coeff 0.2,MeshCellStyle->{1-> Gray, 2-> Gray,3-> Gray}];

RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[zview],{-1,-.5,-.2,-.1,0,.1,.2,.5,1,2}] //Labeled[#,"ViewPoint altitude"]&

Show[
region01 ,
region00,
lightSource,
Axes-> True,AxesLabel->{"X","Y","Z"},Lighting-> 
{{"Point",White,lightSourcePosition},{"Point",GrayLevel[0.8],{0,-160.`,4.`}}},ImageSize-> 800,  
ViewCenter->coeff {0.5`,0.5`,0.5`},ViewPoint->coeff { 0.027,-3.14 ,1.2 zview},  
ViewVertical->coeff {-0.017,-0.49,14.5}] //Dynamic
```

[image]

As mentionned by @HenrikShumacher in a comment of the linked page, `GraphicsComplex` may be better (I'm not a specialist at all).

Comment: The idea of the floating polyhedron is not mine, but I don't remember where I have seen this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot3D[1/(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + 3)*(Cos[
    2*(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + ArcTan[x, y])]), {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}, {-3, 3}}, 
 Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[RGBColor["Aqua"], Specularity[White, 5], Opacity[.8]], 
 Exclusions -> None, Mesh -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: fig1]